# Django's self.client.login(...) does not work in unit tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-authentication, django-testing

I have created users for my unit tests in two ways:

1) Create a fixture for "auth.user" that looks roughly like this:

```
    { 
        "pk": 1, 
        "model": "auth.user", 
        "fields": { 
            "username": "homer", 
            "is_active": 1, 
            "password": 
"sha1$72cd3$4935449e2cd7efb8b3723fb9958fe3bb100a30f2", 
            ... 
        } 
    }
```

I've left out the seemingly unimportant parts.

2) Use 'create_user' in the setUp function (although I'd rather keep 
everything in my fixtures class):

```
def setUp(self): 
       User.objects.create_user('homer', 'ho...@simpson.net', 'simpson')
```

Note that the password is simpson in both cases.

I've verified that this info is correctly being loaded into the test database time and time again. I can grab the User object using User.objects.get. I can verify the password is correct using 'check_password.' The user is active.

Yet, invariably, self.client.login(username='homer', password='simpson') FAILS. I'm baffled as to why. I think I've read every single Internet discussion pertaining to this. Can anybody help?

The login code in my unit test looks like this:

```
    login = self.client.login(username='homer', password='simpson') 
    self.assertTrue(login)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message you got?

Comment: The test case fails on the line, 'self.assertTrue(login)'; the login() function returns False.

Comment: I basically copied&pasted your 2nd variation and it works on Django 1.3. Can you post the entire code including the imports?

Comment: This has been buried somewhere in a code base I no longer access. If I come across the problem I'll be sure to follow-up, but for the record, it was with an earlier version of Django; I think 1.0.2.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

#### The code that doesn't work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client

user = User.objects.create(username='testuser', password='12345')

c = Client()
logged_in = c.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
```

#### Why doesn't  it work?

In the snippet above, when the `User` is created the actual password hash is set to be `12345`. When the client calls the `login` method, the value of the `password` argument, `12345`, is passed through the hash function, resulting in something like

```
hash('12345') = 'adkfh5lkad438....'
```

This is then compared to the hash stored in the database, and the client is denied access because `'adkfh5lkad438....' != '12345'`

#### The Solution

The proper thing to do is call the `set_password` function, which passes the given string through the hash function and stores the result in `User.password`.

In addition, after calling `set_password` we must save the updated `User` object to the database:

```
user = User.objects.create(username='testuser')
user.set_password('12345')
user.save()

c = Client()
logged_in = c.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
```

**OR, using more specialized APIs**:

```
# this encodes the password and calls save()
user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='12345')

c = Client()
logged_in = c.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
```

If you want a super user, use `create_superuser`.

Comment: You an use `User.objects.create_superuser()` and `User.objects.create_user()` that perform exactly this `set_password()` call.

Comment: how about when you log a person in

Comment: to add to @vdboor comment: note that since Django 1.4 also `User.objects.get_or_create()` performs the required `set_password()` call

Comment: @vdboor I agree that one should use `User.objects.create_user()`.

Answer (score 81):

An easier way is to use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login), new in Django 1.9.

```
force_login(user, backend=None)
```

For example:

```
class LoginView(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client.force_login(User.objects.get_or_create(username='testuser')[0])
```

Comment: For some reason, the accepted answer does not work for me, but this one does (and is more concise)

Comment: For some reason, force_login didn't work for me (the page get still returned 302 redirect). Ah well.

Answer (score 7):

Check that `django.contrib.sessions` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` because `client.login()` checks that it is and will always return false if it is not:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions

Comment: +1 for this. Even with `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` in middleware classses you still can not login via django.test.Client. It takes me a week to find this answer

Answer (score 5):

Can you check like below,

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase, Client

class UserHistoryTest(TransactionTestCase):
    self.user = User.objects.create(username='admin', password='pass@123', email='admin@admin.com')
    self.client = Client() # May be you have missed this line

    def test_history(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='pass@123')
        # get_history function having login_required decorator
        response = self.client.post(reverse('get_history'), {'user_id': self.user.id})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

This test case worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **rest_framework**, make sure session-based authentication is enabled. That was my issue.

Go to your settings.py file and check that `REST_FRAMEWORK -> DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` includes `SessionAuthentication`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
    ...
}
```

It looks like the login method uses the vanilla Django session-based approach, so if you were only using rest_framework's token auth that's going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import Client
class MyProfile(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.username = 'dummy' + data + '@gmail.com'
        self.password = 'Dummy@123'
        user = User.objects.create(username=self.username)
        user.set_password(self.password)
        user.save()
        c = Client()
        self.client_object = c.login(username=self.username, password=self.password)
        self.content_type = "application/json"
        response = self.client_object.post('/api/my-profile/', content_type=self.content_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to have an authenticated user during testing the test cases you can use force_login which does not need any authentication properties just pass the user object.

```
    def test_something_view(self):
        client = Client()
        client.force_login(self.user)
        response = client.post(reverse('your custom url'), follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score -4):

If anyone still following this , I think the attributes 'is_staff' and 'is_active' should be kept True for successfully logging in......

`self.user = User.objects.create(username='testuser',password='pwd',is_active=1,is_staff=1)`

Comment: This just worked...........


    self.user = User.objects.create(username='testuser',
                       password='12345',
                       is_active=True,
                       is_staff=True,
                       is_superuser=True)
                       self.user.set_password('hello')
                       self.user.save()
                       user = authenticate(username='testuser', password='hello')
                      login = self.c.login(username='testuser', password='hello')
                      self.assertTrue(login)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `is_staff` which defines wheter access to the admin panel in general is granted. As you can see the data in the initial posting already has `is_active = 1` and that's also the default for `User.objects.create()`.

Comment: @arindamroychowdhury - Wow, that actually worked.. (Your comment, that is)

Comment: It might be a version issue, but I had to comment out your authenticate call.  Other than that, your comment worked like a champ!  On further testing thought, I found that is_active, is_superuser, and is_staff were all unnecessary.  The thing that did it was the call to set_password.